# Received HTTP response headers after- 503 for health check client handler

Tags: c#, .net, azure, kubernetes, health-check

In our dotnet6 project we have implemented health checks in our application and we have deployed our application AzureKubernatiesServices. Recently we started facing some facing some issue. We are able to see the output of health checks correctly but in logs we are getting the fallowing error[image]

we have implemented health check  as bellow.

**health service**

```
        {
            services.AddHealthChecks()
                .AddCheck<DatabaseHealthCheck>("db_health_check")
            .AddCheck<XXXXXAPI_HealthCheck>("XXXXX_health_check")
            .AddAzureServiceBusTopic(configuration["ServiceBusConnString"], configuration.GetValue<string>("ServiceBusConfig:TopicName"), "servicebus_topic_health_check")
            .AddAzureServiceBusSubscription(configuration["ServiceBusConnString"], configuration.GetValue<string>("ServiceBusConfig:TopicName"), configuration.GetValue<string>("ServiceBusConfig:SubscriptionName"), "subscription_health_check");
            services.AddHealthChecksUI().AddInMemoryStorage();
            return services;
        }
```

**ConfigureMethod**

```
{
app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
            {
                endpoints.MapHealthChecks("health", new HealthCheckOptions()
                {
                    Predicate = _ => true,
                   ResponseWriter = UIResponseWriter.WriteHealthCheckUIResponse
                });
                endpoints.MapHealthChecksUI();
            }); 
}
```

**AppConfig**

```
"HealthChecksUI": {
    "HealthChecks": [
      {
        "Name": "HealthChecks",
        "Uri": "http://xxxxx:80/health"
      }
    ],
    "EvaluationTimeInSeconds": 5,
    "MinimumSecondsBetweenFailureNotifications": 60
  }
```

Comment: Issue is resolved. The problem is with Istio N/W policy as it is not allowing the pod to communicate it self. So we added policy to communicate with itself and it worked